# Build Path issues jta-1.0.1B.jar cannot be read or it is not a valid ZIP

Tags: maven, build

I have the following error that causes an exclamation red point on the project and is shown in Problems/Markers View.

'....m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar' ... cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

I have checked in the repository and the jta-1.0.1B.jar is there, I don't get why it cannot be read. I had a different issue on this jar file earlier along with other dependencies like stax-1.0.jar and others and searching for similar issues i saw that there were being caused by the names which had added .lastUpdated at the end of each file. I manually renamed them by only removing the .lastUpdated. After that the build in logs shows success but I still see an error in Markers view and an exclamation red point on the project caused by the listed problem.
i tried this solution:

**Check out the Java.net maven 2 repo.
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/**

Download the .jar, .jar.md5, and .jar.sha1 into you        [.m2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/]

use:

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.transaction -DartifactId=jta -Dversion=1.0.1B -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar

But i still have the same issue. How do I proceed?
Note: Here is what I get in console by running Maven clean [Why does it build successfully and the issue remains?

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [WARNING] 
 [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for prep.mucyo.com:subscription:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path  C:/Eclipse_Juno/workspace/subscription/lib/ojdbc14.jar @ line 84, column 17
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the    stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such    malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building subscription maven webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ subscription ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Eclipse_Juno\workspace\subscription\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.645s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 15 15:45:22 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is part of pom.xml

```
 <repositories> 
<repository>
    <id>JBoss repository</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
</repository>
 </repositories>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>20040902.021138</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>20040616</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>20030911</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.stax</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>C:/Eclipse_Juno/workspace/subscription/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
 <finalName>subscription</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I had to delete the **repository** folder and build again. And I then I encountered the question I had earlier similar to [Finding missing Maven artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036984/finding-missing-maven-artifacts)
And I found that the missing files issues i had first were caused by this dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>20040902.021138</version>
 </dependency>
```

Trying to solve that question similar to the one with missing files  I had just to use a different version of **dom4j** with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and everything else worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your downloaded JAR is corrupted. Try to delete everything inside the "m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B" and repeat the process.

I checked the central repository and there isn't any JARs with this id: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.transaction%7Cjta%7C1.0.1B%7Cjar

You could also change the "version" tag to "1.1", if your situation permits such a change, of course.

The Maven build is succesfully completing probably because the JTA classes aren't needed in compile time, nor by any test units (if any).

Comment: i changed the version to 1.1 and got the following error 'C:/Eclipse_Juno/workspace/subscription/target/stax-stax-1.0.jar' in project 'subscription' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file