# Missing clover jar:1.3-rc4

Tags: dependencies

where can i find this jar: clover:jar:1.3-rc4? I have arrived at this point after there was errors caused by missing files, I want to try this last thing of manually installing clover:jar:1.3-rc4 as i did for stax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the issue similar to [Finding missing Maven artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036984/finding-missing-maven-artifacts) I downloaded these jars to add them manually as the similar question is answered;

```
stax:stax:jar:1.0 
stax:stax-ri:jar:1.0
```

however I could not find

```
clover:clover:jar:1.3-rc4
```

So I got to ask this question. Finally I workaround and I realized that the following errors:

```
Missing artifact stax:stax:jar:1.0    
Missing artifact clover:clover:jar:1.3-rc4
Missing artifact stax:stax-ri:jar:1.0
```

were caused by the following dependency  in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>20040902.021138</version>
</dependency>
```

The solution to all issues is resolved by using a different version of dom4j,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```